# How to show the default value for shortcode if an attribute is not added to the shortcode

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have below a shortcode on my page.

```
[singletextutm url="/about-us/" name="Know more" class="no-bg-button" ]
```

I am using the below code in the function.php and it's working

```
function singletextutmlink($atts, $content='') {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'url' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'icon'=> '',
        ), $atts);
    
    if ($atts['icon'] == 0) {
        $ctaicon ='';
    }
    else {
          $ctaicon ='<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
    }
    
 return $ctaicon;

}
add_shortcode( 'singletextutm', 'singletextutmlink');
```

Now my issue with the below code. I haven't added an icon attribute to my shortcode because I have to set the default icon attribute. I mean if the icon attribute is not added in the shortcode then still it should run the else condition.

```
if ($atts['icon'] == 0) {
        $ctaicon ='';
    }
    else {
          $ctaicon ='<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
    }
```

The expected output in the comment

```
[singletextutm url="/about-us/" name="Know more" class="no-bg-button" icon="0"] // it will display empty $ctaicon

[singletextutm url="/about-us/" name="Know more" class="no-bg-button" ] // Not set icon but still run else conditon  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>

[singletextutm url="/about-us/" name="Know more" class="no-bg-button" icon="1"] // it will display <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

Comment: No, PHP version 7.4.26 (Supports 64bit values). tomorrow we will update to PHP 8

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'url' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'icon'=> null,
    ), $atts);
$ctaicon = (!is_null($atts['icon']) && $atts['icon'] == 0) ? '' : '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
```

First param of `shortcode_atts` means the default k-v, it set the default value of `icon` to null now, so that only if someone
add the icon attribute to 0 it will return ''.

Comment: I have tried this but not working. if I add icon=0 then working, if I add icon=1 then working. my expected output is if someone did not add the icon attribute then it should work like icon=1.

Answer (score 0):

It totally work on my side -

```
add_shortcode( 'singletextutm', 'singletextutmlink');

function singletextutmlink($atts, $content='') {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'newtab' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'icon'=> '',
    ), $atts);
    
    if ($atts['icon'] == 1) {
        $ctaicon =' <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
    }
    
    if ($atts['newtab'] == true) {
        $newtab ='target="_blank"';
    }
    
    $button = "<a href='".$atts['url']."' ".$newtab." class='".$atts['class']."'>".$atts['name'].$ctaicon."</a>";
    return $button;
}
```

With this shortcode -

```
[singletextutm url="https://www.example.com/about-us/" newtab="true" name="Know more" class="custom-btn-primary" icon="1"]
```

[image]

Comment: I'd rather see cleaner markup generation with `sprintf()` instead of messy concatenation.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It would be better coding.

Comment: I have demonstrated in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660077/2943403).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a default in your `shortcode_atts`. `'icon'  => '0'` This sets the icon to be the character (not the integer) '0'.  Then when you're comparing values, you want to look for the character `0` and not the integer.

Also, according to WPCS, you should be using strict comparisons `===` or `!==`

I don't see any use of your other parameters `url` etc in this code, but I assume this is just to understand the issue with the icon param?

```
function singletextutmlink( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'url'   => '',
            'name'  => '',
            'class' => '',
            'icon'  => '0',
        ),
        $atts,
        'singletextutm'
    );

    if ( '0' === $atts['icon'] ) {
        $ctaicon = '';
    } else {
        $ctaicon = '<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>';
    }

    return $ctaicon;

}
add_shortcode( 'singletextutm', 'singletextutmlink' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) for`shortcode_atts()`.

Its logic states that it filters the keys in the `$atts` array by the whitelist of keys in your hardcoded array AND if any of the whitelisted keys are not found in `$atts`, then they will be added to the output array with its hardcoded default value. Any elements with keys not mentioned in the hardcoded whitelist array will be excluded from the returned `$out` array.

All values passed in from the parsed shortcode string will be strings, so you can treat them as such when making conditions/comparisons.

To ensure that the `icon` value defaults to present the Font Awesome icon, set the hardcoded default value to `1`.

To avoid hard-to-read concatenation, use `sprintf()` with placeholders; this will make future maintenance easier too.

I'll use loose/truthy comparisons to determine if values should be included in the returned output string.

```
function singletextutmlink( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'url'   => '',
            'name'  => '',
            'class' => '',
            'icon'  => '1',
        ],
        $atts,
        'singletextutm'
    );

    return sprintf(
        "<a%s%s>%s%s</a>"
        $atts['url'] ? " href=\"{$atts['url']}\"" : '',
        $atts['class'] ? " class=\"{$atts['class']}\"" : '',
        $atts['name'],
        $atts['icon'] ? ' <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>' : ''
    );
}
```